# jnlp - unable to load resource

Tags: java, href, jnlp

I have a JNLP file and want to load resources from a folder. I have quite a few jars and do not want to specifically define each and every one of them. I have tried changing the path to the below but does not work.

```
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.0+" />
    <jar href="lib/*.jar" />
</resources>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify each jar individually.

According to the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)

> jar - Specifies **a** JAR file that is part of the application's classpath.
>
> href - contains **an** url of the jar file.

So I think it is not possible to use wildcards. Especially it doesn't make sense if you want to use one of the other attributes like version, main, download, size etc.